# Angular 2, Recursive function not updating view

Tags: angular

I have this recursive function which calls a service that makes and HTTP request and returns true or false. If it's true, I push a string into the `this.data` array. `this.data` is then used by the view to display the list.

The problem is, the view is not updating automatically. Is there a way I can programatically refresh the view? Or is it simpler than this?

Many thanks

JT

```
checkForFile(dateToday: Date, fileListArray: Array<string>, numberOfFilesToCheck: number) {

        // create the filename to search for
        let dateYesterday: Date = this.createDateForYesterday(dateToday);
        let filenameYesterday = this.createFilenameForDate(dateYesterday) + '_activities.csv';
        this.serverDataService.fileExists(filenameYesterday)
            .toPromise()
            .then((data) => {  // the callback where it all happens
                if (data === true) {
                    this.data.push(filenameYesterday);
                }

                // recurse this method until the array is full.
                if (this.data.length < numberOfFilesToCheck) {
                    this.checkForFile(dateYesterday, fileListArray, numberOfFilesToCheck, callCount);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: so you mean this recursive is happening its just the array's data not rendering on the screen ?

Comment: Are you sure that it is actually ever ending?

Comment: Yes, the data is populating the data array. The data is being used inside a datatable component. If I sort the table, then the data displays. However until I manually take this action on the UI the data won't display.

Comment: Yes, the recursion is ending. I've removed those lines for the example.